# How to add global `AuthorizeFilter` or `AuthorizeAttribute` in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In **ASP.NET MVC 4** and below we just add the following in Global.asax:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = "Admin, SuperUser" });
```

Any idea how to do this in **ASP.NET Core MVC**?

Comment: Did you check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution)?

Comment: @tmg thank you for this one, it seems that it can't be injected to pipeline as "new AuthorizeAttribute()" in core unlike in the previous ASP.NET versions, I`m now looking for a way to migrate the above filter in core.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution):

> You can register a filter globally (for all controllers and actions)
>   by adding it to the `MvcOptions.Filters` collection in the
>   `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup` class:

You can not add `AuthorizeAttribute` into `MvcOptions.Filters` . Create an `AuthorizationPolicy` and use `AuthorizeFilter`:

```
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("Admin", "SuperUser")
        .Build();

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Comment: So I removed the [Authorize] annotation from each controller/action and added your code snippet. Unfortunately, it is not working on my side. I get a 401 :/

Comment: `AuthorizationFilter` seems to be gone along with the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization` nuget package. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20):

You can also use the below code. This is using a type rather than an instance.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(AuthorizeFilter));
});
```

And using Dependency Injection you can resolve the policy Object.

Comment: Could you expand on your contribution a little, such as how to register a Policy for DI ?

Comment: This should be the real answer.

Answer (score 5):

In case if you are using the [Razor Page flavor of the ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start) you could add global filters as follows:

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/"); // Require users to be authenticated.
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/", "YourPolicyName"); // Require a policy to be full filled globally.
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a new answer to expand on @maxspan's answer which I found immensely helpful.

I needed to enforce the presence of bearer token in my API. Here's what I ended up doing.

- Created an authorization policy and injected that as a dependency in `Startup.cs`.

```
AuthorizationPolicy policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
services.AddSingleton(policy);
```

- Created a filter called `BearerTokenAuthorizationFilter` which extends from `AuthorizeFilter` and retrieved the policy dependency.

```
public class BearerTokenAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizeFilter
{
  private readonly AuthorizationPolicy _policy;

  public BearerTokenAuthorizationFilter(AuthorizationPolicy policy) : base(policy)
  {
      _policy = policy;
  }

  public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
  {
    //Use the policy here...
  }
}
```

- Applied this filter on all controllers in my API.

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(BearerTokenAuthorizationFilter));
});
```