# Access Controller from ExceptionFilterAttribute in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

With ASP.Net Core 2, how could you get access to the Controller instance that an ExceptionFilterAttribute is applied to?

Is there a better way to acheive shared "base" controller properties and methods, etc. now in Core? Such as putting it in a higher level like Startup?

Before Core, In MVC 4, I would do something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base controller, shared by all WebAPI controllers for tracking and shared properties.
/// </summary>
[ApiTracking]
[ApiException]
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    private Common.Models.Tracking _Tracking = null;
    public Common.Models.Tracking Tracking
    {
        get
        {
           if(_Tracking == null)
               _Tracking = new Common.Models.Tracking();
           return _Tracking;
        }
    }
    //... other shared properties...
}

/// <summary>
/// Error handler for webapi calls. Adds tracking to base controller.
/// </summary>
public class ApiExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext cntxt)
    {
        BaseApiController ctrl = cntxt.ActionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as BaseApiController;
        if (ctrl != null)
            ctrl.Tracking.Exception(cntxt.Exception, true);

        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Intercepts all requests to inject tracking detail and call tracking.save.
/// </summary>
public class ApiTrackingAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext cntxt)
    {
        //...add info to tracking
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext cntxt)
    {
        BaseApiController ctrl = cntxt.ActionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as BaseApiController;
        if (ctrl != null)
            ctrl.Tracking.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: You never really had to use a base controller to apply attributes to all controllers.  [It's different in core, but you still can apply attributes without a base controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972518/how-to-add-global-filters-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: @ErikPhilips your provided link shows how can add global filters but here question is how we can get controller context in filters

Comment: @programtreasures I get that.  That's why my information is a comment and not a answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpContext` in ASP.Net Core contains `Items` property of `IDictionary<object, object>` type for sharing the data within the scope of the request. It's exactly what you need for covering your case. Here is a sample implementation:

```
public class ApiExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var items = context.HttpContext.Items;
        if (items.ContainsKey("Tracking"))
        {
            Tracking tracking = (Tracking)items["Tracking"];
            tracking.Exception(context.Exception, true);
        }

        base.OnException(context);
    }
}

public class ApiTrackingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var tracking = new Tracking();
        //...add info to tracking

        context.HttpContext.Items.Add("Tracking", tracking);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var items = context.HttpContext.Items;
        if (items.ContainsKey("Tracking"))
        {
            Tracking tracking = (Tracking) items["Tracking"];
            tracking.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is nice to get property by using `HttpContext.Items`, but I am looking for controller context, how can we find `ControllerContext` from `ExceptionContext`

Comment: Earlier there was `ControllerContext` property in `ActionContext` from which  `ExceptionContext` inherits. But it was removed, check [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2097) for details. My answer covers original question, OP does not need `ControllerContext` to achieve his goal.

Comment: Thanks @CodeFuller. I will test this out asap. One of the reasons I always used a base controller was that in the deriving controllers I would also pass this.Tracking through to the helper calls, etc., so the tracking is mainly populated by the helpers. Using context.items should do the trick.

Comment: @CodeFuller this did solve my problem for accessing things in filters. I am struggling still a little with the fact that filters execute unordered... so in my case, tracking is saving before the exception is captured. I will figure that out outside of this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 6 or later, check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72624066/10765136). I provided a sample on how to get access to the controller using a combination of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IActionFilter and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IExceptionFilter.