# How to execute some code after all actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to run code after all Actions in asp.net core.

Apparently, the answer is not to register a new middleware, as middlewares don't have access to the Action return value, they have access to the executed `ActionResult`.

Apparently, the answer is not to define a new `ActionFilter`, as I need to use it on every action.

So here is the question: How can I run code before and after every action in asp.net core, in a way that I have access to method input and output?

Comment: What about an `IActionFilter`? You can add it to filters via options on `.UseMvc(options)`.

Comment: Would it be an option to call this code from the constructor and override Dispose to run code before the controller is disposed.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Interesting suggestion. BTW, I'm looking for a "register once, wroks everywhere" solution.

Comment: @john Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Alireza - ActionFilter could be globally registered and so it will be applied to each action. Look into this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972518/how-to-add-global-filters-in-asp-net-core) for example

Comment: Instead of inheriting from Controller you could inherit from MyController (which inherits from Controller), where you add the lines of code.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg: One shouldn't abuse the dispose pattern for this, when there are clean ways and hooks to do that (action filters, middleware). Dispose is only called when the controller is being disposed/cleaned up and this happens on the **end** of the request. By that time the result has already been written to the stream (connection to the browser)

Comment: ActionFilters and the ability to register them globally is the way to go. Thanks everyone.