# How to restrict google oauth 2.0 to particular domain only in asp.net core web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I am using asp.net core web application, I want to restrict the login only to particular domains like @domain.com , I followed few steps involved in this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCQdo5Njeew for google external authentication which is the older version and I followed this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?tabs=aspnetcore2x
The oauth is working but I want to restrict access to particular domain only, how to do this?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858813/restrict-login-email-with-google-oauth2-0-to-specific-domain-name  It says you need an hd parameter on your challenge.  It also implies it requires OpenIdConnect, but Google's APIs have a lot of overlap.  You can add this parameter by tacking on `?hd=mydomain` to Options.AuthorizationEndpoint. Or use the OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint event.

Answer (score 2):

Restricting the domain upon login from OAuth is not reliable enough. I suggest you create a custom security policy as explained in [Tackle more complex security policies for your ASP.NET Core app](https://jonhilton.net/complex-aspnet-core-custom-security-policies/).

First, you need a requirement:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

public class DomainRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string Domain { get; }

    public DomainRequirement(string domain)
    {
        Domain = domain;
    }
}
```

Then, you need a handler for this requirement:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

public class DomainHandler : AuthorizationHandler<DomainRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        DomainRequirement requirement)
    {
        var emailAddressClaim = context.User.FindFirst(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);

        if (emailAddressClaim != null && emailAddressClaim.Value.EndsWith($"@{requirement.Domain}"))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

With those in place, you can add a new authorization policy in `Startup.cs` so that ASP.NET Core is aware of it:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CompanyStaffOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Email).AddRequirements(new DomainRequirement("company.com")));
    });

    // ...
}
```

Finally, you can refer to this policy when adding an `[Authorize]` on your controller actions:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CompanyStaffOnly")]
public IActionResult SomeAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

See also [How to add global `AuthorizeFilter` or `AuthorizeAttribute` in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41972518/65060) if you want to globally apply this policy.