# Easy-auth whitelisting of pre-approved MSA, Google, Facebook, Twitter accounts

Tags: asp.net-core

Using *Easy Auth*, is it possible to restrict access to an Azure App Service website to a list of pre-approved individuals based on their MSA, Google, Facebook, and/or Twitter identities?

It looks like a custom security policy in the ASP.NET Core website’s codebase can be [configured](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51358992/852956) to perform whitelisting. (I haven’t tried this yet). But I’m curious if there might be a no-code, easy-auth approach that also works.

Comment: AFAIK , there is no such feature in Easy Authentication . Checking in your application after authentication is the workaround at current .

Comment: It's unfortunate that white-listing authorized users is not a feature of Easy Auth.