# How does AuthorizeFilter work with AuthorizeAttribute applied to page?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-authorization

When I have locally applied:

```
[Authorize(Policies.ManagesProducts, AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes.Cookies)]
```

Authorization works fine. However, for global filter I get

```
services.AddMvc(opt =>
    {
        var authorize = new AuthorizeFilter(
            new IAuthorizeData[]
            {
                new AuthorizeAttribute {AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes.ConnectDeviceCookies}
            });
        opt.Filters.Add(authorize);
    })
```

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Debug: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Trace: Authorization Filter: After executing OnAuthorizationAsync on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Trace: Before executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ForbidResult.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ForbidResult:Information: Executing ForbidResult with authentication schemes (Cookies).
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was forbidden.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Trace: After executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ForbidResult.

For the page to which user is redirected after signing in.

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net core, you could not add `AuthorizeAttribute` into `MvcOptions.Filters` . Create an `AuthorizationPolicy` and use `AuthorizeFilter`

```
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AuthenticationScheme)
    .Build();

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972518/how-to-add-global-authorizefilter-or-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Where did I write that I was trying to add `AuthorizeAttribute` as a global filter?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are restricting access to all the controllers, including the login action. For this to work you need to apply an AllowAnonymousAttribute to the login action (GET and POST) as to allow unauthenticated users to login.

Comment: it is applied from the very beginning. And the problem is not with the login page but with the page which is set in `returnUrl`

Comment: That is the login page. And that attribute was not mentioned on your question.